# How to add a button or box below Post Title?

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a Wordpress plug-in that will add a button (or any HTML element) below the post title (or above if below is not possible). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the filter responsable for printing titles. I'm not sure exactly which one it is, but here's the function (it's likely `single_post_title` as demonstrated):

```
add_filter( 'single_post_title', 'the_post_title', 10, 2 );

function my_more_link( $post_title ) {
    $button_code = "your_button_HTML_here";
    return str_replace( $post_title, $post_title . $button_code );
}
```